# MySQL default_socket_timeout timeout only when connecting from ECS Fargate Task

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, connection-timeout

This is a strange one. In my ECS Fargate task, I have a Docker container running PHP code that calls mysqli_connect to connect to an RDS MySQL database. Works great.

However, sometimes I want to stop the RDS database to save money which will cause the mysqli_connect command to fail.

Sample code:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

    echo "done";
?>
```

When I run this from a container in my local environment connecting to a stopped local MySQL database via host.docker.internal, it fails immediately and code continues to execute, which is what I want.

(Corrected) When I run this from a container in my local environment connecting to the SAME stopped RDS MySQL database, it waits for the PHP default_socket_timeout value (default 60 seconds) then fails and code continues to execute. I want it to fail immediately.

When I run this from a container in my Fargate task, it waits for the PHP default_socket_timeout value (default 60 seconds) then fails and code continues to execute. I want it to fail immediately.

I realize I can set the default_socket_timeout to 1 second. I've done that and seen it fail after 1 second instead of 60, but why is this the only scenario where default_socket_timeout is invoked?

UPDATE: I figured out part of the cause and it has to do with the AWS RDS instance. When it's running and I purposely make the value of $hostname, $username, $password, or $database wrong, it will fail immediately. Only when I stop the RDS instance will it wait for default_socket_timeout seconds no matter if the code is running in a Fargate task container or local container.

My solution was to avoid the default_socket_timeout delay entirely by calling the AWS describe-db-instances API periodically to get its status before calling mysqli_connect().

Comment: @Dharman As a MySQL expert, do you have any thoughts on the question? :-)

Comment: Do you have any minimal code at all? I'm not a PHP dev, but I want to see if I can reproduce this. It might be code? Might be Docker configuration? Might be something else? Too many factors here, why not start with making them both connect to the same RDS database to remove the possibility of RDS DB config causing this?

Comment: Thanks @ErmiyaEskandary for making me research my problem more. I added simple code in the question and figured out the default_socket_timeout is ALWAYS invoked when the AWS RDS instance is stopped, which I guess make sense since the endpoint no longer exists. Is there a fast way to tell if the RDS endpoint exists before calling mysqli_connect? Would I be "safe" if I reduce default_socket_timeout to 1 since the task and the RDS instance are in the same AWS Region (but not same Availability Zone)?

Comment: Aha there we go :) you would be safe yes - why do you want to immediately disconnect? Do you need 24/7/365 guaranteed connectivity?

Comment: I want to be able to stop the database to save money, but want the code that connects to it to fail gracefully and quickly. Since my last message, I found that I could check the status of the instance with the AWS command 'aws rds describe-db-instances', but that also takes about a second to run. There are ways to improve AWS CLI speed (https://dzone.com/articles/how-i-made-aws-cli-300-faster-full-disclosure) but not sure I want to go that far...

Comment: Just switch it off and let your application hit the regular timeout? If your application is still up and running, you're paying for it whether it is trying to connect to your DB or not. Stop the DB and let the application run (if you need to). What are you trying to truly achieve here? Set the timeout to something like 5 seconds if the retrying is personally bugging you.

Comment: In terms of graceful failure, scale down the application before you turn off the DB if you're trying to save cost (unless you need other aspects of the application). You can't gracefully fail on a DB being shut mid-application unfortunately.

Comment: I decided to write a little cached status function to be called right before calling mysqli_connect(). It saves a tiny json file to the server that contains the RDS instance status and an expiration datetime. The function will only call the AWS API to get the status of the instance if the current datetime is past the expiration datetime, then save the new status and an expiration datetime (which will likely be 15 minutes in the future). It should be fast enough to not significantly impact performance.

Comment: I would update the question as your initial Q is no longer valid :)

Comment: Sorry, to answer your question above, the RDS instance is relatively expensive when turned on, and it only really needs to be available periodically on demand. So with the above solution, I can turn it on and wait less than 15 minutes for it to be ready.

Comment: Yes, it's very common to scale down. My concern was - shut the application down too if you're turning the DB off.

Comment: Ah, I should have explained that the application just becomes a static webserver that doesn't need a database when I turn the database off!

Comment: Yes so **turn them both off - why are you worried about graceful failure?**